# What are some GUI clients available for Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Also, where would I find them?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Tortoise HG](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/).  All the tortoise goodness, now for Mercurial.

**UPDATE july 2020:**
The original official website linked above is abandoned.

The project moved to: https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/tortoisehg/thg

Comment: Cool. If you think of any more, add them to this answer.

Comment: I loved tortoisesvn on windows. Do real people use TortoiseHg for Mac yet (Dec 2009) (it isn't obvious from their page)?

Comment: I tried tortoise HG for windows. I really like it. I never found a port yet tho for the Mac. I'm currently using Murky...like a minimal HG client. Doesn't support tagging.

Comment: anybody with an ncurses hg UI suggestion, if one even exists? i'm digging tig for git big time.

Comment: I love TortoiseHg but the Mac version is not worth the trouble. I tried installing but it requires too many dependencies. After one hour compiling stuff the compiler failed and I gave up and installed MacHG.

Comment: I don't understand the statement about the links... from what I can see https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/ is still up to date.  The heptapod link is correct but that is for THG developers, not end users.  https://www.mercurial-scm.org/ also hosts THG installers and might be a better additional link?

Answer (score 16):

GUI clients & Other tools: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/OtherTools

Answer (score 16):

IMO best GUI Hg client for OSX is SoureTree - http://sourcetreeapp.com

I was using MacHg, which is ok (and free), but SourceTree has better support, ongoing development and better workflow.

Comment: SourceTree was recently acquired by Atlassian, makers of Jira.  This means even more resources going into the product. Great news, IMO.

Comment: SourceTree seems to be free now.

Comment: SourceTree is indeed free, after signing up on their website. IMHO the most mature GUI application for Mercurial.

Comment: I just installed SourceTree, and Mercurial is not supported. http://sourcetreeapp.com/faq/

Comment: I like the feel of SourceTree, eg. it provides an easy interface for resolving merge conflicts.

Comment: @northben Take another look – Mercurial [wasn't](https://web.archive.org/web/20130501061507/http://sourcetreeapp.com/faq/) in the Windows version before 1.0, but it is now.

Answer (score 6):

If your on OSX then [MacHg](http://jasonfharris.com/machg) is IMHO quite nice. (I wrote it and maintain it...)

Comment: Given the last update on the site is dated 2014 I'm guessing it's no longer maintained? Plus a high-rated issue raised in its BitBucket site is that it's not compatible with recent versions of Mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using eclipse:

http://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main

Answer (score 2):

If you're an OS X user, [Murky](http://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/wiki/Home) is pretty decent.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code has a simple plugin for a few basic operations:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrcrowl.hg

The pending changes are highlighted in the editor and support for the basic commit/push/pull/update workflows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the console you can check out: https://bitbucket.org/lc2817/hgv

Answer (score 0):

There is also `hgview` http://www.hgview.org/ which has a ncurses based CUI somewhat like `tig` as well as a GUI for viewing the logs. You can only view the logs from this program, but that is really all I want a user interface for.